# Polars: Tracking Data lineage(New,Existing,Updates,Deletes) between 2 Dataframes

Tags: python-polars, rust-polars

I have 2 datasets (Day1 and Day2) that can have 100s of columns.

> The problem statement is I have to track on Day2 dataset
>
> 1. What records are existing from Day 1
> 2. What records got updated.
> 3. What records are brand new.
> 4. And lastly, what records in Day1 are not in Day2 (Deletes, if we say)

I implemented it as below, but I feel its not an efficient approach. There must be a better way and I need your help on this.

For this example, we will consider 2 small dataset with few columns so we can visually see the changes.

> columns : emp_id ┆ ename ┆ salary ┆ dob
> primary_keys: emp_id ┆ ename

> day1_df

```
┌────────┬───────┬────────┬────────────┐
│ emp_id ┆ ename ┆ salary ┆ dob        │
│ ---    ┆ ---   ┆ ---    ┆ ---        │
│ i64    ┆ str   ┆ f64    ┆ str        │
╞════════╪═══════╪════════╪════════════╡
│ 111111 ┆ Jeetu ┆ 111.11 ┆ 22/04/1992 │
│ 222222 ┆ Neetu ┆ 222.22 ┆ 01/05/1989 │
│ 333333 ┆ Steph ┆ 333.33 ┆ 06/07/1976 │
│ 444444 ┆ Diana ┆ 444.44 ┆ 01/04/2003 │
└────────┴───────┴────────┴────────────┘
```

> day2_df

```
┌────────┬────────┬────────┬────────────┐
│ emp_id ┆ ename  ┆ salary ┆ dob        │
│ ---    ┆ ---    ┆ ---    ┆ ---        │
│ i64    ┆ str    ┆ f64    ┆ str        │
╞════════╪════════╪════════╪════════════╡
│ 111111 ┆ Jeetu  ┆ 111.11 ┆ 22/04/1992 │  # Existing
│ 333333 ┆ Steph  ┆ 723.15 ┆ 06/07/1976 │  # Updated Salary
│ 555555 ┆ Anwar  ┆ 555.55 ┆ 12/04/1987 │  # New Record
│ 222222 ┆ Janice ┆ 222.22 ┆ 01/05/1989 │  # New Record as we have a composite primary key
└────────┴────────┴────────┴────────────┘    and there's a change in ename.
```

To get What records are updated, I create a join on primary key and then go on checking individual columns if there is an updates.

```
diffs = day2_df.join(day1_df, on=primary_keys, suffix="_day1").with_columns(
    pl.any_horizontal([pl.col(x) != pl.col(f"{x}_day1") for x in day2_df.columns if x not in set(primary_keys)]).alias(
        "Updated"))
    

┌────────┬───────┬────────┬────────────┬─────────────┬────────────┬─────────┐
│ emp_id ┆ ename ┆ salary ┆ dob        ┆ salary_day1 ┆ dob_day1   ┆ Updated │
│ ---    ┆ ---   ┆ ---    ┆ ---        ┆ ---         ┆ ---        ┆ ---     │
│ i64    ┆ str   ┆ f64    ┆ str        ┆ f64         ┆ str        ┆ bool    │
╞════════╪═══════╪════════╪════════════╪═════════════╪════════════╪═════════╡
│ 111111 ┆ Jeetu ┆ 111.11 ┆ 22/04/1992 ┆ 111.11      ┆ 22/04/1992 ┆ false   │
│ 333333 ┆ Steph ┆ 723.15 ┆ 06/07/1976 ┆ 333.33      ┆ 06/07/1976 ┆ true    │
└────────┴───────┴────────┴────────────┴─────────────┴────────────┴─────────┘
```

And then I count:

```
updated = diffs.filter(pl.col("Updated") == False).select(pl.count()).collect()[0, 0]

existing = diffs.select(pl.count()).collect()[0, 0] - updated
```

For New Records in Day 2 and Records Deleted of Day 1, I do anti joins.

```
new_day2 = day2_df.join(day1_df, on=primary_keys, how="anti", suffix="_day1").select(pl.count()).collect()[0, 0]
deletes_day1 = day1_df.join(day2_df, on=primary_keys, how="anti", suffix="_day2").select(pl.count()).collect()[0, 0]

> Updated: 1 
> Existing: 1 
> New on Day 2: 2 
> Day 1 Deletes: 2
```

While this works, and I get the result, I believe 3 Queries to perform this task is not ideal.

Comment: FYI, [`item`](https://pola-rs.github.io/polars/py-polars/html/reference/dataframe/api/polars.DataFrame.item.html#polars.DataFrame.item) is the Polars idiomatic way of getting the scalar out of a (1,1)-shaped DataFrame.

Comment: Perhaps `day1.sort("emp_id") == day2.sort("emp_id")` could be used as a starting point.